# Python Pseudo-code rewording code

Tags: python

```
if num > 1:
   for i in range(2,num):
       if (num % i) == 0:
               print(num,"is not a prime number")
               break
   else:
       print(num,"is a prime number")

else:
   print(num,"is not a prime number")
```

I have some python code here and was wondering on how to do pseudo code.

Comment: Just read the code and write it down in the way you say it in your head

Comment: Python makes pretty good pseudo code already for users of other languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how strict the pseudo-code syntax you're following is, but something along these lines should be OK:

```
IF num > 1 THEN
    FOR i = 2 to num
        IF remainder num / i = 0 THEN
            PRINT num + " is not a prime number" 
        ELSE
            PRINT num + " is a prime number"
        ENDIF
    ENDFOR
ELSE
    PRINT num + " is not a prime number"
ENDIF
```

I'm assuming that the first else statement is missing an indent and corresponds to the "if (num % i) == 0". It's also worth noting that you'll want a space at the start of the strings in your print statement so that there is a gap between 'num' and the rest of the string.

Take a look at this site for some more info about psuedo-code: http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~jdalbey/SWE/pdl_std.html